# Progress Bar Value Calculation - Equation

Tags: vb.net, progress

Right so I have 2 progress bars and the equation that I have made to calculate the progress of the second progress bar (The overall progress) in theory should work fine. It works fine for the first download but then when it gets to the second download instead of continuing it jumps to 100 straight away.

Now I am not sure if this is because of my custom progress bar or because of something else.

This is my code for the progress bar.

```
If CProgressBarCurrent.Value >= 1 Then
    CProgressBarTotal.Value = (100 * (currentFileNumber - 1) + CProgressBarCurrent.Value) / Me.fileUrls.Count
End If
```

These are the functions:

```
Dim currentFileNumber As Integer = 1
```

I add one to it every time a download is finished.

```
CProgressBarCurrent.Value
```

Value of my first progress bar which shows how much of the file it has downloaded. Byte wise.

```
Me.fileUrls.Count
```

Amount of files in the queue.

I have also tried another equation which was this:

```
CProgressBarTotal.Value = (currentFileNumber / Me.fileUrls.Count + CProgressBarCurrent.Value / 100 / Me.fileUrls.Count) * 100
```

This partially works also but it had the same problem. When the first download was completed instead of continuing it would just go to 100%.

I manage this via a timer tick. So for every tick it will do carry the process out.

This is my Progress Bar max value property:

```
    Property Maximum As Double
    Get
        Return MaxValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        If MaxValue < 0 Then MaxValue = 0 Else If MaxValue < MinValue Then MaxValue = MinValue
        MaxValue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This is my Value property:

```
    Property Value As Double
    Get
        Return Percent
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        If value < Minimum Then value = Minimum Else If value > Maximum Then value = Maximum
        Percent = value
        If Percent = 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Width = CInt(value * 3.74)
        Else
            PictureBox1.Width = CInt(value * 3.74 / Maximum * 100)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

My Declarations:

```
    Protected MinValue As Double = 0.0
Protected MaxValue As Double = 100.0
Protected Percent As Double = 0.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of the Maximum property on the progress bar?

Comment: Edited my original post with the code for the property of maximum and value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct equation is the following:

```
CProgressBarTotal.Value = ((currentFileNumber - 1) + CProgressBarCurrent.Value / 100 ) * 100 / Me.fileUrls.Count
```

This come from two parts:

```
percentOfCompletedFiles  = (currentFileNumber - 1) / Me.fileUrls.Count * 100
percentCurrentFileReferredAllFiles = CProgressBarCurrent.Value / Me.fileUrls.Count
```

added toghether and simplifying the Whole.

Some conditions has to be met in order this to be working:

- Me.fileUrls maintain also the already downloaded urls in the list
- CProgressBarCurrent.MaxValue = 100
- CProgressBarCurrent.Value returns double or float (or integer division issues may occur)

Comment: The problem still occurs. When the first file is completed and the second file starts, it still goes to 100% event though it's not meant to.

Comment: In the formula with (currentfileNumber - 1) actually it is 2/3 + 50% / 3 that gives 83.333%. Are you sure not to increment currentFileNumber "at beginning of download" instead than "at the end of download"? ..because in that case it will alwais be 1 higher then expected.. ..and last resort: output in a textbox the result of the formula and see if the result is wrong (and the actual wrong value will help in understanding) or if it is a visualization matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the maximum of the second progress bar to File.Urls.Count and add 1 for every file completed it should work fine.